# Why is my 2D Maze not being painted with JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, maze, jcomponent

UPDATE: I Figured out the problem and wrote it out below.If you'd like to see the full compliable code here it is on GitHub: https://github.com/scohen40/cohen-mco364-fall-2018/tree/mazeGUI/src/main/java/cohen/maze

I have a 2D Array of Cells, each with 4 walls. My generateMaze() class starts at a random point and digs out a maze. That part works correctly, and when I print out the maze in the console everything is fine.
My next goal is to have the maze painted out with a JComponent in a JPanel. The problem is that all I'm getting is one thick-lined box in the top left corner. 
Here's the painting code:

```
public class AnimatedMaze extends JComponent {
private Maze maze;
private int componentHeight;
private int componentWidth;
private int seventhHeight;
private int seventhWidth;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    componentHeight = this.getHeight();
    componentWidth = this.getWidth();
    seventhHeight = componentHeight/7;
    seventhWidth = componentWidth/7;

    maze = new Maze(7, 7);
    g.setColor(Color.black);

    paintMaze(g);

}

/**
 * The paintMaze() method runs through the generated maze and paints the existing walls.
 * @param g
 */
void paintMaze(Graphics g) {
    for (int x = 0; x < maze.getHeight(); x++) {
        System.out.println("|");
        for (int y = 0; y < maze.getWidth(); y++) {
            Cell current = maze.getMaze()[x][y];
            if(current.isWestWall()) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + seventhHeight);
            }
            if(current.isNorthWall()){
                g.drawLine(x, y,x + seventhWidth, y);
            }
            if(current.isEastWall()) {
                g.drawLine(x + seventhWidth, y, x+ seventhWidth, y + seventhHeight);
            }
            if(current.isSouthWall()) {
                g.drawLine(x, y + seventhHeight, x + seventhWidth, y +seventhHeight);
            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

You can see in the console the generated maze but in the JPanel it'sjust a box.
[image: Issue]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your app does? And also explain how it differs from what you want.

Comment: *"Any ideas as to the problem are welcome."* The code is broken. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is there anything missing from the code example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Not only are there things missing (including class closing braces and methods referenced in the code shown) but an MCVE  / SSCCE should be a single 'copy / paste / compile / run' so can have only a single public class. Furthermore, I expect this problem could be reproduced in an example using much (*much*) less code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I took out the last two code samples as they weren't completely necessary. Hopefully, the question isn't too bogged down by extra lines now. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @SarahCohen you should double check that the code in the question will compile and run to produce the behavior you are asking about

Comment: The code currently posted has no imports and is missing the `Maze` and `Cell` classes. *"It compiles with no errors."* Maybe for you, there, in your IDE that includes imports automatically and already has access to the classes missing from above, but that it completely not what we need, in order to help you. I'll bring you back to something said earlier: @Code-Apprentice *"you should double check that the code in the question will compile and run"* By that we meant you should copy/paste the code your are about to put in a question here, into a completely new project of your IDE and check it ..

Comment: .. compiles, runs and demonstrates the problem with ***absolutely no changes.*** If  you could not be bothered doing that, why should anyone else? You have a vested interest in solving the problem, our interest is purely academic.

Comment: @SarahCohen I get several compiler errors when I try to compile the code you have shared with us. As I said earlier, you need to make sure that the code **in this question** compiles.

Comment: @SarahCohen I restored the Maze and Cell classes but they are incomplete and will not compile, either. In order to help you, we need a code example which has no compiler errors and reproduces exactly what you see.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism. I will bear it in mind for my next question. I actually figured out the problem and wrote it out below. If you'd like to see the full compliable code here it is on GitHub: https://github.com/scohen40/cohen-mco364-fall-2018/tree/mazeGUI/src/main/java/cohen/maze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer by Krzysztof Cichocki, realized that coordinates work differently from rows and tables. I switched the x's for y's and vice versa, after multiplying everything by seventhHeight. Also any additions that I did to any coordinate is always seventhHeight now, to make everything proportional. 
Here's the current code for the painting method:

```
    void paintMaze(Graphics g) {
    for (int x = 0; x < maze.getHeight(); x++) {
        System.out.println("|");
        for (int y = 0; y < maze.getWidth(); y++) {
            Cell current = maze.getMaze()[x][y];
            if(current.isWestWall()) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine((y+1)*seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight, (y+1)*seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight + seventhHeight);
            }

            if(current.isNorthWall()){
                g.drawLine((y+1)*seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight,(y+1)*seventhHeight + seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight);
            }

            if(current.isEastWall()) {
                g.drawLine((y+1)*seventhHeight + seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight, (y+1)*seventhHeight + seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight + seventhHeight);
            }

            if(current.isSouthWall()) {
                g.drawLine((y+1)*seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight + seventhHeight, (y+1)*seventhHeight + seventhHeight, x*seventhHeight +seventhHeight);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is now what happens:
[image: final maze printing picture]

Comment: If you like my answer you can approve it.

Answer (score 2):

In your painting code you need to multiply every x and y coordinate by 'seventhHeight', otherwise you are not painting to correct coordinates.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for the tip, I fixed the whole method working off your answer.